# Angular `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` not redirecting to page

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` to redirect to an overview page if a nonexistent url is entered. Currently, everything works with the project and no errors are received however I am not being redirected to

```
http://localhost:8081/browse/overview.html
```

when entering a nonsensical url such as

```
http://localhost:8081/browse/overviewasdasd.nonExistent
```

Instead, I see a white page with `Not Found` on it. All help is appreciated.

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse/overview.html');
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's going wrong?

The `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse/overview.html');` is working fine, but there is no state defined by `$stateProvider` that assigns that URL to a particular state.

> How to fix this?

You need to add a state for this particular situation.The code will look like this:

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse/overview.html');

    $stateProvider.state('home',{
      url:'/browse/overview.html',
      templateUrl: "urlOfTheTemplate.html"
    })
}])
```

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bFiqVYkyn3sQKmJM8JD2?p=preview).